# Why won't my regex parse this URL in Django?

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

Currently working in Django, and I'm trying to set things up so that a form on one page calls a specific URL, for which the appropriate view is rendered. I'm having trouble with the regular expression that parses the URL, as it won't read the value '\?' as an escaped question mark, which is what I believe it should be doing. The following RE checks out on Pythex.

When the app submits the form, it calls the URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/map/?street=62+torrey+pines+cove&city=san+diego&state=CA&radius=50&drg=4
```

In my project level urls.py file, I have the following:

```
url(r'^map/', include('healthcare_search.urls', namespace="healthcare_search")),
```

This calls my app level urls.py file, where I have:

```
    url(r'^\?street=(?P<street>[a-z0-9+]+)&city=(?P<city>[a-z+]+)&state=(?P<state>[a-z]{2})&radius=(?P<radius>[0-9]{1,3})&drg=(?P<drg>[0-9]{1,3})', views.map_hospitals, name = "map_hospitals"),
```

This just results in a 404 error, saying the URL doesn't match any of the patterns. I know that it's a RE problem, because I removed everything from the app level RE, and submitted just `http://127.0.0.1:8000/map/` to see if it would call the right view, which it did successfully. Things seem to break apart on the '\?'. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

As a note, this is the first time I've written a regular expression, so my apologies if it is unclear or poorly written.

Comment: If you need to work directly with the URL string, you could try the `urllib.parse` module in the Python standard library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to get access to the variables that way.  A better option is to get them from the request, since they'll be available in the `request`'s dictionary of variables.  In your view, you can get the value of `street` via `request.GET.get('street', None)`, which will return the value if `street` is in the request or return `None` otherwise.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much. Is there a way to do this without having the variables automatically put into the URL? If I'm not going to pull them out of it, I'd rather it just be clean and not have the extra info...or is that just how the request is passed regardless?